# Loading data from a table in a Map as Column Name Vs Value using Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hql, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-generic-dao

I have been using Hibernate for a while and this time I am trying to do something uncoventional here. Not even sure of its possible.

What I want to do is to load data from a Single table, where in few of this columns will have fields defined for them for rest (almost around 20 and can increase with time) all integers, I want to load them in a Map. Such that the name of the Column become the key and and the data its value.

I am using Hibernate 4.1.4 and using Annotations to map Fields with Columns.

As further clarification:
Table Definition :

```
CREATE TABLE TempTable
(
 id SERIAL,
 revId TEXT,
 type INTEGER,
 group INTEGER,

 col_1 INTEGER,
 col_2 INTEGER,
 col_3 INTEGER,
 col_4 INTEGER,
 col_5 INTEGER,
 col_6 INTEGER,
 col_7 INTEGER,
 col_8 INTEGER,
 col_9 INTEGER
}
```

The DAO Model would look something like

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TempTable")
public class StatsModel {
    private Long entryId;
    private String revId;

    private Integer type;
    private Integer group;

    private Map<String, Integer> metrics; // Map in which I want columns col_1 to col_9 as "Column Name" Vs. "Value"

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "serial")
    @Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
    public Long getEntryId() {
        return entryId;
    }

    public void setEntryId(Long entryId) {
        this.entryId = entryId;
    }

    @Column(name = "tx_rev")
    public String getRevId() {
        return revId;
    }

    public void setRevId(String revId) {
        this.revId= revId;
    }

    @Column(name = "nu_type")
    public Integer getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(Integer type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Column(name = "nu_group")
    public Integer getGroup() {
        return group;
    }

    public void setGroup(Integer group) {
        this.group = group;
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean a naming strategy? or you want to load not annotated fields?

Comment: @Ziul I am sorry, I didn't understand that. I am not sure if there are any annotations which can be used to load data from a table directly in a Map. Also, this is a single table I am trying to read from. There are no JOIN or anything here, Just 1 table and 1 DAO model for it.

Comment: @Ziul I have updated the question text further to add Table Schema from which I am trying to read data from. I hope this explains my question better.

Answer (score 0):

could use a view of the remaining columns to "pivot" the columns.  Then map this view, e.g. a view created like this (note even the DDL for the view could be dynamically created by reading the data dictionary of your db, but that is another question!)

```
create or replace view TempTable_metrics as
select t.id,
       pv.name as key,
       case
          when pv.name = 'COL1' then t.col1
          when pv.name = 'COL2' then t.col2
          when pv.name = 'COL3' then t.col3
       end as value
from   temp_table t,
       (
       select 'COL1' as name from dual union all
       select 'COL2' as name from dual union all
       select 'COL3' as name from dual
       ) pv
```

Edited: (adding how to do the hibernate part)
Forgot to mention, on the java side you need these annotations by your map:

```
@CollectionTable(name="TempTable_metrics", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id"))
@MapKeyColumn(name="key", nullable=false)
@Column(name="value")
Map<String,Integer> metrics;
```

Just realized though that in order to do updates you'd need some messy "instead of" triggers in your DB (I've done this with Oracle but elsewhere YMMV).

Answer (score 0):

You can load your data as a map changing your query, this is the hibernate doc example:

```
select 
    new map(
        max(bodyWeight) as max,
        min(bodyWeight) as min, count(*) as n 
    ) 
from Cat cat
```

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select